# VS 2010 RC. Is it "final enough to install w/o worry?"

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I used to install betas freely and learned the hard way that I best only do that using a disposable environment.

What is your perception of the safetey of installing the Release Candidate version? Is it likely that when I go to install the final version that I will be faced with having to do ugly manual steps to get rid of it just so I can install the actual release version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just un-installed beta 2 from a machine I use to code on (not my main work dev PC though) fairly frequently. The uninstaller does a very good job of tidying up and only left behind the Visual Studio Tools for Office runtime. I then installed the RC and everything went fine and nothing seems to have broken. Based on the beta 2 uninstaller behaviour I expect the RC should uninstall nicely when RTM time comes around .

That said, the usual caveats that apply to all pre-release software still apply here. If the machine you're thinking of installing onto is mission critical then don't take the risk, use a VM or a machine you can afford the time to rebuild instead.

Comment: will the RC expire like beta2?

Comment: I've always had horrible performance with Virtual MAchines, even though I have plenty of hard disk space on my external TB drive and about 3.5 GB of RAM. Adjusting the memory slider to and fro don't seem to help. I'm dumbfounded why I see demos of people using VMs while getting decent performance, else I would go right for the VM approach. Thx for the reply.

Comment: @Benny - "VS2010 RC is licensed for use through June 30, 2010 at which point you’ll need to upgrade to the final release to continue using the product." - http://blogs.msdn.com/jeffbe/archive/2010/02/08/going-live-with-the-visual-studio-2010-release-candidate.aspx